# mySQL Queries in Wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a mySQL database table called stock which holds a stock record on items for sale.  When querying the database using PHP I have no issue, but when I try to do it through Wordpress it doesn't work.

my PHP is as follows

```
// Query the stock level
function QueryStock($cat) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM stock";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    if (!$result) die ("Database access failed: " . mysql_error());
    $rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
    for ($j = 0 ; $j < $rows ; ++$j)
    {
        $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
        if ($row[0] == $cat) {
            $catno=$row[0];
            $supplier=$row[1];
            $itemname=$row[2];
            $category=$row[3];
            $price=$row[4];
            $stock=$row[5];
        }
    }
    mysql_close($db_server);

    echo "There are " . $stock . " bears";
}
```

`$cat` in the function attribute is the catalogue number of the item I am querying and the output is "There are 2 bears".

I put this in Wordpress and the webpage hangs.  Then through Google searching, I found out about the $wpdb object being used by Wordpress at [designmodo.com](http://designmodo.com/wpdb-object-wordpress/). So with some code condensing too, I changed it to...

```
function QueryStock($cat) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM stock WHERE catno = " . $cat;
    global $wpdb;
    $row = $wpdb->get_row($query, ARRAY_N);
        $catno == $row[0];
        $itemname = $row[2];
        $price = $row[4];
        $stock = $row[5];

    echo "There are " . $stock . " bears";
}
```

Now the output is "There are bears" (missing the `$stock` value). I have been doing loads of Google searching to get where I am and I am having problems understanding it.  Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Just a BTW: you should not read '*' columns, this is too brittle if the order of the columns change and it is also inefficient if you do not need all columns.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Eureka!!!,

It's often something missed, and it was in the MySQL query.

The query should be `SELECT * FROM stock WHERE catno = '$cat'` making `$query = "SELECT * FROM stock WHERE catno = '$cat'";`

I have taken on board the "SELECT *" issue @eckes and @rickonline pointed out, went for separate queries and used `$wpdb->get_var()`.

Working coding is..

```
function QueryStock($cat) {
    $query1 = "SELECT catno FROM stock WHERE catno = '$cat'";
    $query2 = "SELECT itemname FROM stock WHERE catno = '$cat'";
    $query3 = "SELECT price FROM stock WHERE catno = '$cat'";
    $query4 = "SELECT stock FROM stock WHERE catno = '$cat'";

    global $wpdb;

    $catno = $wpdb->get_var($query1);
    $itemname = $wpdb->get_var($query2);
    $price = $wpdb->get_var($query3);
    $stock = $wpdb->get_var($query4);

    echo "There are " . $stock . " bears";
}
```

Comment: Is your catnr a string? Then yes, you'll need to do it this way. On the other hand: why isn't your primary key an integer?

Also: what @eckes and I meant was not that you ought to get your variables in four different queries. You should only refrain from using "SELECT *". In your example, it would become "SELECT catno, itemname, price, stock FROM stock WHERE catno = '$cat'".

Comment: The catno is made up with reference to supplier and their catalogue number. I felt that the primary key would be better being the catno as each item has a different catno and therefore can be referenced by the catno instead of having id 1 to whatever

Comment: The reason why I put each variable into 4 different queries was because I had an issue with extracting the variable from an array generated within Wordpress.  Both ways (using "SELECT *" and "SELECT catno, itemname, price, stock FROM stock WHERE catno = '$cat'") would generate arrays so doing it this way is a work around

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
function QueryStock($cat) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM stock WHERE catno = " . $cat;
    global $wpdb;
    $row = $wpdb->get_row($query);
        $catno = $row->catno; //Column name in table
        $itemname = $row->itemname; //Column name in table
        $price = $row->price; //Column name in table
        $stock = $row->stock; //Column name in table

    echo "There are " . $stock . " bears";
}
```

Also, I would advise against using "SELECT *". Try to query only for the columns used. This is better for performance.

Edit: saw a typo. You had "$catno == $row..." in your code. You should only use one "="

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the typo.  Unfortunately the suggestion still didn't work.  Got the same output

Comment: Is the table stock in the same database as your WordPress tables?